# What is the max value of numeric(19, 0) and what happens if it is reached?

Tags: sql-server

In an SQL Server table, I have a column with the following type:

```
numeric(19, 0)
```

What is the max value for this type?

This corresponds to a `Long` in Java, which has a maximum value of `9,223,372,036,854,775,807` (19 digits).

Does the above type in SQL Server have the same max value?

What happens in SQL Server if the above value is reached?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms187746.aspx) rather unhelpfully says:

> When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1...Maximum storage sizes vary, based on the precision.

(max precision is `numeric(38)`).

From experimenting in SQL Server 2012, **the maximum value for `numeric(19,0)` is 10e18 - 1025**.  Attempting to insert any higher value gives:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 6, Line xx   Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric.

The maximum does vary by precision and appears to be a bit under 10^(p-1) (where p is precision), though the exact relationship is not obvious.  No doubt a more exact answer could be given by delving into the bit-level details of the storage method.

Answer (score 2):

`numeric(19,0)` specifies a fixed precision number having a precision of 19 digits and 0 digits to the right of the decimal point.  It should not overflow.  See [decimal and numeric](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) for more information.

Comment: The MSDN link says "When maximum precision is used, valid values are from - 10^38 +1 through 10^38 - 1".  So apparently there is a limit and this answer is incorrect, though the docs don't say how that limit varies by precision or what happens when you exceed it.

Answer (score 1):

First, decimal is synonimous with numeric.
decimal (2, 1) means that total number of all digits summed before and after dot can be maximum 2 and the number of digits after dot can be maximum 1. So range is from -9.9 to 9.9
Range for numeric(19, 0) is thus

```
-9999999999999999999.0 to
9999999999999999999.0
```

But sometimes also

```
9999999999999999999.2
```

will be allowed from my experiments, don't know why.